# How to check bootstrap alert contains inner class alert-dismisable?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

How can I get inner classes using jquery?
I know that I can cath it by `$(".alert")` but then I need to know if it dismissable or not? For exmaple here I want to get false value.:

```
<div class="alert alert-danger fade in">
    Some info
</div>
```

And here to get true:

```
<div class="alert alert-danger fade in alert-dismissable">
    Some info
</div>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [hasClass](http://api.jquery.com/hasclass):

```
$('.alert').hasClass('alert-dismissable');
```

Comment: Thank you, that's what I need!